# How to remove \" when writing R character objects to JSON

Tags: json, r, elasticsearch

I have a `data.table` like this one:

```
test <- data.table(city = c("Berlin", "Berlin", "Berlin", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdam"),
                   key1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
                   value1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   value2 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),
                   kpi = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30))
```

I would like to upload these data to Elasticsearch, but with a specific structure:

```
library(RJSONIO)
res <-test[, .(factors = toJSON(.SD)), 
             by = .(city, key1), 
             .SDcols = c("value1", "kpi")]
```

This code creates, in the column `factors`, different JSONs. Since I want to get rid of the `\n` sequences that the library introduces, I can substitute these strings in the assignment:

```
res <-test[, .(factors = gsub("\n", "", toJSON(.SD))), 
         by = .(city, key1), 
         .SDcols = c("value1", "kpi")]
```

The problem comes when I want to upload this object to Elasticsearch (I'm using the `elastic` package). Since R uses backslashes to escape double quotes within a character string, when I write the object using:

```
docs_bulk(res, "index")
```

It writes `\"` instead of `"` in the string fields that were created using the inner `toJSON` (`value1` and `kpi`). This can also be checked when writing the object into a file:

```
write(toJSON(res), "~/output.json")

{
 "city": [ "Berlin", "Amsterdam" ],
"key1": [ "A", "B" ],
"factors": [ "{ \"value1\": [1, 2, 3 ],\"kpi\": [10, 15, 20 ] }", "{ \"value1\": [ 4, 5 ],\"kpi\": [25, 30 ] }" ] 
}
```

Since the names of the `value1` and `kpi` start and end with `\"`, these fields are not parsed by Elasticsearch as separated arrays. What I would want to have is something like this:

```
{
 "city": [ "Berlin", "Amsterdam" ],
"key1": [ "A", "B" ],
"factors": [ { "value1": [1, 2, 3 ],"kpi": [10, 15, 20 ] }, { "value1": [4, 5 ],"kpi": [25, 30 ] } ] 
}
```

I have tried several different combinations of regexs `gsub` but I'm unable to prevent R from writing the backslash. My last option would be to write the object to a file and parse it manually with `sed`, but I think there should be an easier way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `elastic` maintainer here: that works for me. i'm on `elastic` `v0.7.6.9500`, and Elasticsearch `v2.3.5` - what versions are you running?

Comment: Hi @sckott I'm using Elasticsearch 2.3.3 and `elastic` v0.7.6. For me, it also loads the file to Elasticsearch without errors, but the problem is that the field  `factors` is: `"{ \"value1\": [      1,      2,      3 ],\"kpi\": [     10,     15,     20 ] }"`, so it is parsed as a whole string, not as an object with two arrays. Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: when I wrote "not correctly parsed", I didn't mean that it generates an error, but since the backslashes are introduced by R, it isn't parsed as I expected. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Do you want to end up with this? https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/2r2g2H2k0m1N0e0Q2E3Y/Screen%20Shot%202016-10-06%20at%209.01.35%20AM.png

Comment: @sckott Yes, that's what I would want to have.

Comment: see answer, load in as a list insetad of a data.frame. when a data.frame, each cell of the table is treated as a single string or number/whatever the data type is, but as a single thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay, i think this should do it. could be less code to get to the final `res` object to load in bulk, but anyway

```
library(elastic)
library(data.table)
library(jsonlite)

test <- data.table(city = c("Berlin", "Berlin", "Berlin", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdam"),
                   key1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
                   value1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   value2 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),
                   kpi = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30))

res <- test[, .(factors = jsonlite::toJSON(.SD, dataframe = "columns")), 
           by = .(city, key1), 
           .SDcols = c("value1", "kpi")]

res <- lapply(apply(res, 1, as.list), function(z) {
  tt <- z[!names(z) %in% "factors"]
  tt$factors <- fromJSON(z$factors)
  tt
})

docs_bulk(res, "mycoolindex")

curl 'http://localhost:9200/mycoolindex/_search?size=1' | jq .
#> {
#>   "took": 13,
#>   "timed_out": false,
#>   "_shards": {
#>     "total": 5,
#>     "successful": 5,
#>     "failed": 0
#>   },
#>   "hits": {
#>     "total": 2,
#>     "max_score": 1,
#>     "hits": [
#>       {
#>         "_index": "mycoolindex",
#>         "_type": "mycoolindex",
#>         "_id": "AVeay0KnlE0U0vVWYXkb",
#>         "_score": 1,
#>         "_source": {
#>           "city": [
#>             "Amsterdam"
#>           ],
#>           "key1": [
#>             "B"
#>           ],
#>           "factors": {
#>             "value1": [
#>               4,
#>               5
#>             ],
#>             "kpi": [
#>               25,
#>               30
#>             ]
#>           }
#>         }
#>       }
#>     ]
#>   }
#> }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel: I have an identical question but I don't find the answers in here so very clear. Did you get a simple solution to remove the \ from the toJSON written as a character output?  The solution given by sckott looks bulky and not sure if it addresses the removal of \ or something else. I will wait for your comment before I raise a fresh SO question.

Comment: @sanjmeh No, I didn't try a simpler implementation.

Comment: Ok. So I will raise a fresh question which will be a copy of your question. I feel someone is going to mark it a duplicate. Do you have a suggestion how to get around asking for more answers to your questions?